# Position an image in a paragraph to avoid changing line spacing

Tags: html, css

In this image:

[image: Paragraph with image]

I have an image (an svg) that is inline in the paragraph. The size of the svg is 30 x 30. But it forces the line spacing to increase on the line where the svg is located. Is there a way of preventing this other than having to modify the svg file itself?

Comment: Can you add a hand-drawn border which illustrates the size of the .svg or snippet?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I think you must change the image itself. Because if the image is bigger than the height of the texts it will increase the spacing no matter what.

Comment: Yes the image  height is larger than the line spacing. But I was wondering whether some kind of cropping or overflow could be provided to eliminate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `vertical-align:middle;` to `SVG` image as shown below:

```
svg{
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Well that certainly works but I was looking for a solution without modifying the svg. If no one else has provides one, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @AndroidDev No need to modify svg just add this css in your code it will work

Comment: At first I thought that it works. For the most part it does. But if I set the height of the svg to 30, there still is an obvious spacing difference between the line above an below. While setting vertical-align to middle helps a lot, it isn't perfect. Was hoping that some cropping or overflow property might be used.

Comment: Try to add some negative margin-top and -bottom on the image, https://jsfiddle.net/mszLofbv/ (you’ll have to figure out which exact values work, maybe involve `calc()` to use a combination of a relative unit related to the font-size and the pixel height of the image …)

Comment: @AndroidDev is it possible to share your code? or if image height is 30px then set line-height:30px to your paragraph